# I need match string in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need to match string within `""` , I'm using following it's not working

```js
var str='"hi" hello "abc\nddk" ef "gh"';

console.log(str.match(/(?=")[^"]*?(?=")/));
```

t's giving me output as

```
[]
```

I need output as

```
["hi", "abc\nddk", "gh"]
```

**Update :**

I can use regex `"[^"]"` to match string in quotes but I need to avoid the `"` from the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way would be to do:

```
/"[^"]*?"/g
```

This will return an array with `"hi"`, `"abc\nddk"` and `"gh"` and you can do something like `piece.replace(/"/g, "")` on individual pieces to get rid of the `"`.  If you don't like that then rather than do a `match` you can do a [search and don't replace](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/)

```
var matches = [];
str.replace(/"([^"]*?)"/g, function (_, match) {
    matches.push(match);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain, why shouldn't my regex works

Comment: @PranavCBalan the lookahead `(?=")` doesn't actually _consume_ the `"` so `(?=")[^"]` will never match anything.

Comment: @PranavCBalan http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html -- read this as many times as you need to. Lookarounds are _zero width assertions_. They don't consume characters.  So `(?=")` means "match the location that is followed by a `"`. So `(?=")[^"]` is match the location followed by a quote, then match any character that is not a quote -- this is a contradiction.

Comment: also look behind is not supported in JavaScript regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`/(?| (")((?:\\"|[^"])+)\1 | (')((?:\\'|[^'])+)\1 )/xg`

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG3qR3/2)

BTW: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rX4rL7/1) is a great resource to use (which is where I got the regex above)

### Update

The first one I posted works for PHP, [here is one](https://regex101.com/r/jB6hM0/1) for JS

`/"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\w+|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/g`

Comment: It's giving me error in console as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'xg'`

Comment: Ah, yes I see that now. hmm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I read your question incorrectly but this is working for me

`/\".+\"/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/wF0yN4/1

Comment: That regex doesn't work if you try this string: `"hi" hello "abc\nddk" ef "gh"`

Comment: I need only string within the quotes

Comment: @KevinJantzer Oh so an escaped `\\n` must be part of the string? Sorry, misunderstood